# Styles disappear for a second print command

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using this JavaScript code for print functionality.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    Main.init();
    //FormValidator.init();
    $('#printButton').click(
        function(){
            var divContents = $("#printPage").html();
            console.log(divContents);
            var printWindow = window.open();
            printWindow.document.write(
                '<html>' +
                '<head>' +
                '<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= base_url() ?>assets/css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print"/>'+
                '<title></title></head>'
            );
            //printWindow.document.title = '';
            printWindow.document.write ('<body>');
            printWindow.document.write('' +
                '<div class="page-title"> <h1 class="page-title"> BeaconHouse Potohar Campus</h1>' +
                '<h2 class="page-title">Mid-Year Profile</h2></div>'
            );
            printWindow.document.write(divContents);
            printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
            printWindow.document.close();
            printWindow.print();
        });
    });
```

In my HTML I have a button with id="printButton". When I click that button this script opens a new tab in my browser with the options to print page and a print preview (CSS style applying fine at this point). But if I cancel the print close the tab and go back to press the print again all the style is gone from my print page. Refreshing by ctrl+shift+R or ctrl+f5 doesn't solve the issue.it is very annoying that I have to log out and wait and then log in to be able to see the style again getting applied on my print page. How to remedy this problem?

Comment: Docuemnt.write is not like writing a string.

Comment: apparently removing those extra document.write statements (appending all the html in one document.write line) has solved the issue.